# Not able to show NA in IsError function in MS Access query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to display 'NA' in my calculated field when the result shows error with following query.But it shows the result but for error it still showing either #Div/0! or #Num!.How can I solve this .my calculated field expression bulider is :

```
costDiffPerc: IIf(IsError(FormatPercent([costDiff]/([tb_MasterData]![Inq Gross Price]))),'NA',FormatPercent([costDiff]/([tb_MasterData]![Inq Gross Price])))
```

Please help me how to fix this..I just want to show NA if there is error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that doesn't seem to work.

It is better to prevent the error instead of trying to catch it:

```
costDiffPerc: IIf([tb_MasterData]![Inq Gross Price]=0, 'NA', FormatPercent([costDiff]/([tb_MasterData]![Inq Gross Price])))
```

Comment: Thank you Andre..it worked..I just need to edit the code like this since my column data type was text:costDiffPerc: IIf([tb_MasterData]![Inq Gross Price]='0', 'NA', FormatPercent([costDiff]/([tb_MasterData]![Inq Gross Price])))